# Find different values in a column grouped by another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose a table like the extract below:

| ITEID | SUBSTITUTECODE | SUBSTITUTEDESCR | MASTERQTY | SUBSTQTY | SUBSTITEID | COLORCODE | SIZEPOS | ISEAN13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4454 | 3468336065181 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 7 | 0 |
| 4454 | 3468336065754 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 6 | 0 |
| 4456 | 3468336053201 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ Λ | 7 | 0 |
| 4456 | 3468336053287 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ Λ | 8 | 0 |
| 4456 | 3468336057391 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ Λ | 9 | 0 |
| 4456 | 3468336058664 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ Λ | 6 | 0 |
| 4462 | 3468336073957 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 1 | 0 |
| 4462 | 3468336073995 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 3 | 0 |
| 4462 | 3468336074152 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 2 | 0 |
| 4462 | 3468336074381 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 13 | 0 |
| 4462 | 3468336074503 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 11 | 0 |
| 4462 | 3468336074664 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 9 | 0 |
| 4462 | 3468336075012 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ | 5 | 0 |
| 4464 | 3468336152294 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ ΠΡΑ | 9 | 0 |
| 4464 | 3468336155493 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ ΠΡΑ | 7 | 0 |
| 4464 | 3468336155578 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΑΥ ΠΡΑ | 8 | 0 |
| 4469 | 3468336206249 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΠΛΕ | 2 | 0 |
| 4469 | 3468336206300 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΠΛΕ | 9 | 0 |
| 4469 | 3468336206546 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΠΛΕ | 11 | 0 |
| 4469 | 3468336206676 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΜΠΛΕ | 5 | 0 |
| 4511 | 3468335382395 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΚΟΚ | 3 | 0 |
| 4511 | 3468335382401 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΚΟΚ | 4 | 0 |
| 4511 | 3468335382418 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΚΟΚ | 5 | 0 |
| 4511 | 3468335382425 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΚΟΚ | 6 | 0 |
| 4511 | 3468335382432 | NULL | 1 | 1 | NULL | ΚΟΚ | 7 | 0 |

Using a SQL Server query, I would like to make sure/check at a glance that all rows grouped by `ITEID` have the same value in the field `COLORCODE`... One way I could think of (in MySQL though, which I'm familiar with) would be to use a `GROUP_CONCAT(COLORCODE) ... GROUP BY (ITEID)` which unfortunately doesn't work in the SQL Server.

Can someone familiar with SQL Server craft the appropriate for me please? Thank you in advance.

Edit:

An expected result would be something like this:

| ITEID | CONCATENATED_COLORCODE |
| --- | --- |
| 4454 | ΜΑΥ |
| 4456 | ΜΑΥ Λ |
| 4462 | ΜΑΥ |
| 4464 | ΜΑΥ ΠΡΑ |
| 4469 | ΜΠΛΕ |
| 4511 | ΚΟΚ |
| 4511 | ΚΟΚ |
| BUT -> 5000 | NAVY, something_else |

So at a glance, I would notice that for `ITEID` 5000, the person who inserted the data, made a mistake...

Comment: Good day, The "the extract below" is not a table but a text. In order to provide solution we need table with the data. **Please provide queries to create the table and insert the sample data.** In addition please describe the expected result according the sample data

Comment: The full table has 1000+ rows, and I'm sure the person who entered the data, has made a mistake... So, before I further process the data, I would like to make sure that indeed all the same ITEID rows have the same COLORCODE values... This extract has the same values, but in 1000+ rows, there must be a mistake...

Comment: @RonenAriely I honestly didn't know I had to write the queries that would create the table for anyone who would like to give it a shot! It's my first SQL-related question! I edited my original question and added the expected result, but anyway, a nice person has already given me another solution, by counting the distinct colors of the same ITEID! Thanks anyway.

Comment: "I honestly didn't know I had to write the queries": This is OK. We are here to help you, so you learned something new `:-)` You know now for next time. "Thanks anyway" : You are most welcome +1

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on posting SQL questions. Including 7 extraneous columns of sample data doesn't really narrow down the problem, does it?

Comment: `STRING_AGG` works fine in SQL Server, not sure what you mean. Unless you are on SQL Server 2016 or earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe?
(please do the set up work yourself next time)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS YT

CREATE TABLE YT(
   ITEID           INT  NOT NULL
  ,COLORCODE       NVARCHAR(7)
 
);
INSERT INTO YT(ITEID,COLORCODE) VALUES
 (4454,N'ΜΑΥ'),(4454,N'ΜΑΥ'),(4456,N'ΜΑΥ Λ'),(4456,N'ΜΑΥ Λ'),(4456,N'ΜΑΥ Λ')
,(4456,N'ΜΑΥ Λ'),(4462,N'ΜΑΥ'),(4462,N'ΜΑΥ'),(4462,N'ΜΑΥ'),(4462,N'ΜΑΥ')
,(4462,N'ΜΑΥ'),(4462,N'ΜΑΥ'),(4462,N'ΜΑΥ'),(4464,N'ΜΑΥ ΠΡΑ'),(4464,N'ΜΑΥ ΠΡΑ')
,(4464,N'ΜΑΥ ΠΡΑ'),(4469,N'ΜΠΛΕ'),(4469,N'ΜΠΛΕ'),(4469,N'ΜΠΛΕ'),(4469,N'ΜΠΛΕ')
,(4511,N'ΚΟΚ'),(4511,N'ΚΟΚ'),(4511,N'ΚΟΚ'),(4511,N'ΚΟΚ'),(4511,N'ΚΟΚ')
-- ADDED DATA TO DEMONSTRATE YOUR QUESTION
,(4511,N'ΚΟΚ'),(4511,N'BAL'),(4511,N'NIK'),(4511,N'DIK'),(4511,N'ΚIΚ')
;

SELECT   ITEID, COUNT(DISTINCT COLORCODE) AS cnt
FROM      YT
GROUP BY ITEID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COLORCODE) > 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry I honestly didn't know I had to write the queries that would create the table for anyone who would like to give it a shot! It's my first SQL-related question!

Anyway, regarding your answer, indeed that's a great solution. Counting the distinct colors! Ah, brilliant! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: if you provide the code to set up your sample data AND the code to show your expected results...it is so much easier for people to help you  (copy and paste into their own test system)...additionally it much reduces the amount of potential confusion in sql speak and languages.  Took me longer to create the demo than provide the answer :-)
Good luck !

Comment: GrahamH yeah, I can imagine, sorry about that! Next time I'll know! Btw, I just realized I had tried your solution but wrote it like `SELECT ITEID, COUNT(DISTINCT(COLORCODE)) FROM ... GROUP BY ITEID`... How uncool is that?